# Wierd sound from headphone on ubuntu 14.04.1 lts

Tags: 14.04, headphones, noise

For some reason there is a weird, static-y noise coming from my headphones.
It goes away when i'm playing a video or music, or have the sound settings open.
I'm using Ubuntu from a usb.

I'm a complete newbie at Linux. Help.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, recently I've also noticed strange sounds, especially while NOT playing music. From my short experience those may be:

- Related to Ubuntu 14.04? I see nothing we can do but report that at the bugs website.
- Static? I suggest making sure Your computer is grounded (power supply connected via 3 wires not 2, consistent all the further way). Sometimes - like in my case, there is no real grounding in the house while fake third bolt / hole sits in the wall sockets, this may be actually dangerous and should be fixed.
  But this is all hoping Your computer is grounded correctly inside.
- Two of my CPU went's wings once flied away seeking freedom (do not recommend, they ended up in the trash with a very miserable look), this causes serious vibrations to my notebook (after few mins random things on the table starts resonating, this is actually quite fun) and can influence electronics (like tiny disconnections of headphones).

All these 3 points can be possible since recently so I have no idea whatsoever.